# Finding the volume of a solid generated by revolving

Tags: calculus

I have this problem here:

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region below about the $y$-axis.

$$    R : {y= e^x, x\le0, y=0}$$

So using the shell method, I've gotten down to the integral

$$2\pi \int xe^x dx$$

$$u = x, du = dx \dots v = e^x, dv = e^xdx$$

$$2\pi (xe^x - \int e^xdx)$$

$$2\pi (xe^x - e^x)$$

$$2\pi e^x (x - 1)\bigg|_{-\infty}^0$$

$$2\pi [(e^0 ( 0 - 1)) - e^{-\infty} ( -\infty - 1))]$$

V = 2pi * -$\infty$?? That doesn't make sense for a volume, where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct until v = 2pi [e^x (x - 1)] from -infinity (-I) to 0

I am not familiar with latex on this site. So I will post an image of my work.

[image: Worked Answer]

I hope this answers your question and message me if you are still stuck.

--- Where you Went wrong ---

You made a mistake here

2pi [(e^0 ( 0 - 1)) - e^-I ( -I - 1))]

Note that e^(-I) is equal to zero since e^(-I) is equal to 1/e^(I).

Then your answer would be 2*pi*[1(-1)-0(-I-1)] ===> 2*pi*[-1] = -2*pi

Volume cannot be negative as corrected by @FatalProphet and therefore the absolute value of -2*pi which is 2*pi is the final answer.

Comment: You explained well where the OP went wrong, nice job. I had a question though, how is negative volume a possibility?

Comment: @FatalProphet Your observation is correct, negative volume is not a possibility. To find the volume in this case we use the integral and calculating the integral gives a negative answer. I was too focused on the calculation that i forgot what the question itself was. In this case we need to take the absolute value of the answer. Note we are using the tools in maths which can give us "unusual answers" and it is our job to make sense of the answer. The answer has been corrected and thank you for notifying me :-)

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic tutorial on MathJax.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks @boywholived